# Light shudder on idle speed

Tags: vw, rough-idle, golf

I have a 2003 Golf 1.9 TDI pd 100 with 120,000 on the clock.

When I have the engine running at idle , after a about 30sec to a minute, it starts to shake a little, like as if an injector is not getting enough fuel. It like runs smooth then after each 30 seconds or so it starts doing it again. If I increase the revs slightly it's ok and the car runs ok. Anyone know what it could be?

Comment: Is the AC on when it does this?

Comment: For understanding: You are saying the engine starts and stays running without issue. Then, on a very cyclic basis, will run rough for ~30 seconds, then smooths out for ~30 seconds, and will continue cycle like this until you rev the engine up some. After that it doesn't do it anymore until you shut the engine down. Does that cover it?

Comment: Does the vibration change / cease if you press the clutch pedal?  These cars have a dual mass flywheel and the first indication that they need replacement is a judder or vibration.

Comment: @SteveMatthews how would that explain the periodic nature of the shudder, though?

Comment: No the a/c was not on ,but did press it on and off to see if any difference but alas no there was not .                                                  Yes Paul, that about sums it up , and answer to Steve , yes I think I did press clutch pedal and it was still doing it , will check again on that though tomorrow and come back to you .      cheers  spike